# Duplicate rows created when removing and then adding rows to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a slight problem getting a `DataGridView` to work properly. Currently, I have a `DataSource` to bind my data (in this case a `List<T>` of objects) and have the following method to bind the data to the control:

```
private void Bind(List<CAMPDomainLayer.FeeDefinition> fees)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(fees, null);
    dgvFees.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    var colDesc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Description",
        DataPropertyName = "Description",
        ReadOnly = true,
        AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader
    };

    var colAmount = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        HeaderText = "Amount",
        DataPropertyName = "FeeAmount",
        ReadOnly = false,
    };

    var colDelete = new DataGridViewButtonColumn
    {
        HeaderText = string.Empty,
        Text = "Delete",
    };

    dgvFees.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { colDesc, colAmount, colDelete });
    dgvFees.DataSource = bs;
}
```

Notice, that I'm adding a button column for a delete button, I'm currently handling that with the following event:

```
private void dgvFees_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(dgvFees.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;

        dgvFees.Rows.RemoveAt(index);
        dgvFees.Refresh();

        CalculateTotal(Fees, PaymentAmount);
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine. The `dgvFees.Rows.RemoveAt(index);` line removes the row from the control *and* the item from the underlying `List<T>`. The problem comes if I try to add a new row. Right now, I have a refresh button that grabs a list from the server and re-binds using the above `Bind()` method. The code to do that is:

```
Fees = fees;
Bind(Fees);
```

Where `Fees` is just a `List<T>`. When this is run, and I delete a row (right now there's) everything works fine. The row is deleted and the underlying list has nothing in it. But when I try to refresh (hence adding new rows), I get this:

[image: Duplicated row]

The hat first row is duplicated, and appended *horizontally* to the first row. What stmpus me is right **before** we rebind, we can see that the `DataSource` only has one item:

[image: Right before we bind, note that the DataSource on has one item in it]

Even **after** binding, I can inspect and see that there is still on *1* item in that datasource:

[image: After we have rebound, I can still only see 1 item in that DataSource]

So my question is, why, if there is only one item in the `DataSource`, can I see a duplicate row. Is the old `DataSource` somehow "phantomed" in there? Is this an issue becuase of my biding approach (which admittedly, I don't know much about Winforms) or is this some bug in the framework?

Comment: You need `dgvFees.Columns.Clear();` at `Bind` method, before adding the columns.

Comment: Looks like you're adding columns but no rows...

Comment: dgvFees.Columns.Clear(); then dgvFees.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] { colDesc, colAmount, colDelete });
    dgvFees.DataSource = bs;